# How does copy work after sftp and scp fails?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a problem with a copy task from the remote server onto my local host. I get the following errors

```
[WARNING]: sftp transfer mechanism failed on [ip addr]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
[WARNING]: scp transfer mechanism failed on [ip addr]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
```

But then it seems to copy it anyway. Note that I am trying to transfer a relatively big file.

```
 changed: [hostname] => {
"changed": true,
"checksum": "aae8e59d29853312c5b80ca73a46ca8b6afebc16",
"dest": "/path/to/dest",
"md5sum": "5997876ce55e3c628e8ef137e03ebbaa",
"remote_checksum": "aae8e59d29853312c5b80ca73a46ca8b6afebc16",
"remote_md5sum": null
```

}

Also when I then try to copy the file from my local host onto another remote node, it does it with no issues.

This is my code:

```
        - name: Copy file.
          fetch:
            src: foo/file.txt
            dest: /path/to/file/
          flat: yes
```

I researched the issue and there are several solutions. However, my question is, how does the copy succeed in the end when it has failed sftp and scp?

Comment: First of all these are warnings not errors. Second, try increasing the verbosity of your output by `-v` option.

Comment: Hi bosari, this is with -v and debug. Also the warnings say "failed" so I assume it's using alternative ways of coping it. I edited the question to show what the copy returns.